# name 'settings' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I add urls in these lines for media and image output to the template. But I meet such a bug.
**name 'settings' is not defined**
 How do I fix it?

```
urlpatterns =+ patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
```

Comment: This is not a bug. Just an error.

Comment: Seems like you would benefit from an introductory Python tutorial. All of the issues you are describing on this page are basic Python.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add

```
from django.conf import settings
```

to the top of your file. And change the operator used in `urlpatterns` variable assignment.

```
urlpatterns =+ patterns('',
```

should be

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
```

There is no `=+` operator in python.

#### EDIT:

From the `urlpattern` posted in comment, I see that there is no other `urlpattern` and the `urlpattern` should be as follows without the `+` sign.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, }),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }),
)
```

Comment: **name 'urlpatterns' is not defined**

Comment: Post your full `urls.py` content.

Comment: from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from social_auth.views import complete
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),)

Comment: Post this in your question. Not in comments.

Comment: Don't you use any other `urlpatterns`?

Answer (score 7):

Add

```
from django.conf import settings
```

To the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you! It helped! But now here's the mistake: **bad operand type for unary +: 'list'** If I change the place of the operands, then get **name 'urlpatterns' is not defined**

Comment: `=+` should be `+=`, and update the question with your complete `urls.py`.

Comment: this leads to: **name 'urlpatterns' is not defined**

Answer (score 1):

for anyone struggling with this situation first thing make sure you have

`from django.conf import settings`

in your `urls.py` file